# Which avatars of Vishnu took place in Kaliyuga?

Tags: avatars, kali-yuga

Which avatars of Vishnu took place in Kaliyuga? And are there canonical scriptural references for Avataras like Venkateshwara Puri Jagannath, et al?

Answer (score 2):

Vishnu took some incarnations during Kali Yuga.

1. **Lord Buddha**

> *“tataḥ kalau sampravṛtte sammohāya sura-dviṣām |
> buddho nāmnāñjana-sutaḥ kīkaṭeṣu bhaviṣyati ||” (SB 1:3:24).*
>
> *“Then, in the beginning of Kali-yuga, the Lord (Vishnu) will appear as Lord Buddha, the son of Añjanā, in the province of Gayā, just for the purpose of deluding those who are envious of the faithful theist”.*

2. **Chaitanya Mahaprabhu**

> *“kṛṣṇa-varṇaṁ tviṣākṛṣṇaṁ
> sāṅgopāṅgāstra-pārṣadam
> yajñaiḥ saṅkīrtana-prāyair
> yajanti hi su-medhasaḥ||“ (SB 11.5.32)*
>
> *In the Age of Kali, intelligent persons perform congregational chanting to worship the incarnation of Godhead who constantly sings the names of Kṛṣṇa. Although His complexion is not blackish, He is Kṛṣṇa Himself. He is accompanied by His associates, servants, weapons and confidential companions.*

3. **Swaminarayana**

He is mentioned as Samaveda-singing brahmin, according to [this experct](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc371757.html) from Skanda Purana.

> 42-43. When the Asuras killed by me (as) Kṛṣṇa and by Arjuna in the battles, will promote and establish Adharma (unrighteous practices) on the earth, I, sage Nārāyaṇa, shall be born on the earth from my devotee Dharmadeva in the land of Kośala, as a Brāhmaṇa-singer of Sāman hymns.

And, the entire [Venkatacala Mahatmya](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc370679.html) from Skanda Purana is fully decrisbed about Venkateshwara form of Lord Vishnu.

Jagannatha is also have scriptural basis in [Purushottama-kshetra mahatmya](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc370720.html) of Skanda Purana. But, Jagannatha is not an avatar of Vishnu, he is Krishna himself.

**N.B.:** Different people might have different opinions.

I hope this clarifies your queries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both have scriptural basis.

- The story of god Venketeshvara maybe read from the Section 1 - [Veṅkaṭācala-māhātmya](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc370679.html), Book 2 - Vaiṣṇava-khaṇḍa of the Skanda Mahā-Purāṇa, **or**, from [Chapter 240](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc627028.html), Prabhāsa-kṣetra-māhātmya, Prabhāsa Khaṇḍa
- The mention of god Jagannath's story maybe found in the [Chapter 19](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc370739.html) or [Chapter 25](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc370745.html), Section 2: Puruṣottama-kṣetra-māhātmya, Book 2 - Vaiṣṇava-khaṇḍa
  **Or**, from [this abridged version](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brahma-purana/d/doc57566.html) of the Brahma Purāṇa

Comment: Swami Vivekanand mentioned in conversation with a Marathi as to how Shivaji Maharaj was a prophesied avatar of God,as per scripture..(He didn’t specifically name the scripture though)

Comment: No, I don't believe those sorts of theory @Amethyst. .. That "said" scriptures might be an interpolation. Chhatrapati Shivaji was a great Statesmen and Ruler, not a descension of some god. Ofc that's my personal views about this proposition.

Comment: You only answered to the mentions about Venkateshvara and Jagannatha in scriptures. But, The user also asked which avatars of  Vishnu took place in Kali Yuga.